# Worship the creator but not his creation. Or worship the creator not his creation

Tags: word-usage, phrase-usage

One of my friends status "worship the creator but not his creation". Is it a valid sentence? Is there any rule in but vs not usage?

Comment: Both are valid. I would probably put a comma in if there is no 'but' (but a comma is possible even with the 'but')

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Grammatically either way is correct, however the second version requires a comma without the 'but'.

> "Worship the creator but not his creation."
>
> "Worship the creator, not his creation."

Comment: This is correct.  I would mention a nuance.  The second sentence has more the sense of a preference, advice to choose one over the other because it is a better choice.  The "but" in the first sentence is more explicitly exclusionary.